# Neo4j cypher query performance issue with movie recommendation query

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I'm currently working on a movie recommendation query that should return the movies with the most "recommendation impact" using the following cypher query:

```
match (m:Movie) 
with m, size((m)<-[:LIKED]-(:User)-[:LIKED]->(:Movie)) as score
order by score desc
limit 10
return m.title, score
```

After reading the graphdb (neo4j) e-book my assumption was that this whould be an easy query for neo4j but the execution time took 32737 ms which is not what I was expecting. Does any one have experience with these kind of queries and has any suggestions to improve performance? Or should this query perform well and do I need to do some neo4j / java configuration tuning?

The profile of the query:

[image]

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is something you can pre-calculate.

Your score is related to the number of movies liked by each user. Why not calculate and store the number of movies liked by each user (assuming a user can only like a movie once, not multiple times)?

Note that this only makes sense if you only care about the number of movies liked by each user, and are okay with adding those up, even if they represent multiple likes of the same movie across many users.

```
MATCH (u:User)
SET u.likedCount = SIZE((u)-[:LIKED]->(:Movie))
```

You will need to update this every time the user likes (or unlikes) another movie.

When this is pre-populated for all users, your scoring query now becomes:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WITH m
MATCH (m)<-[:LIKED]-(u:User)
WITH m, SUM(u.likedCount) as score
ORDER BY score desc
LIMIT 10
RETURN m.title, score
```

EDIT

This of course includes the likes from each user of the movie in question. If you really need to account for this, you'll need to adjust your with to:

```
WITH m, SUM(u.likedCount) - count(u) as score
```

If you only want to count distinct movies liked by users in your scoring, then you can't pre-calculate and have to use something like stdob--'s answer.

Comment: In this specific scenario pre-calculating seems to be the way to go since the realtime statements take at least 30 seconds. I do think that the marketing around the neo4j graph db is a little misleading since (after reading the graph db book) I expected that neo4j can handle these kind of real time queries with ease. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think when the subgraph considered by the query gets into the tens of millions that things do slow down. There is also a difference between doing this kind of query across every movie in your db (of which there are about 10k) vs getting the score for a single movie, or even a handful, which would probably be considering subgraphs of thousands of nodes rather than millions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
MATCH (M:Movie)<-[:LIKED]-(:User)-[:LIKED]->(R:Movie)
WITH M, 
     size( collect(distinct R) ) as score
RETURN M.title as title, 
       score 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

As an option:

```
MATCH (M:Movie)<-[:LIKED]-(:User)-[:LIKED]->(R:Movie)
RETURN M.title as title, 
       count(R) as score
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This moved back the amount of db hits from 44038477 to 266085 but doubled the execution time from 30920 to 62125

Comment: The second statement (option) took 54320 which is 20 seconds slower then the original statement in my question. Any other suggestions?